# What if binary operation is applied to elements in and not in the set?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a set.

What are the consequences of choosing $a \in G$ and $b \notin G$ on the result of their binary operation and the closure property?

What *axiomatic* argument would you give to support that $ab$ need not be in $G$?

Even if in the case $G$ is a proper subgroup of some H?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I have been having trouble making questions more informative. So I degraded to a lesser informative format. Thanks, I'll improve on it.

Comment: Is the setting you mean the following: $G\le H$ and $b\in H\setminus G$?

Comment: @user750041 let it be one of the cases. So, yes.

Comment: In this case, necessarily $ab\in H\setminus G$; in fact, otherwise, $a^{-1}ab=b \in G$: contradiction.

Comment: @user750041 thanks, I used your argument to finish my proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ SL_n(R)$ the set of 
$n ×n$ matrices with real entries whose
determinant is equal to $1$. 
$GL_n(R)$, the set of invertible 
$n  × n$ matrices with real entries is a group under matrix
multiplication.$SL_n(R)$ is a proper subgroup of $GL_n(R)$.
You can find an element which is not in $SL_n(R)$ but in $GL_n(R)$ and an element in $SL_n(R)$. They do not  satisfy closure axiom.

Comment: I am looking for a axiomatic argument not an example

Comment: I have edited. Still this example will work.

Comment: Can you give an axiomatic approach?

Comment: Take an element(matrix) from $GL_n(R)$ whose determinant is not 1 then this element will not in $SLn(R)$.Now take an identity element(identity matrix) from $SL_n(R)$ . Under the operation of multiplication resulting matrix determinant has not be value 1. So closure property fails for $SL_n(R)$

Answer (score 1):

The operation on $G$ is only defined on elements of $G$.  You can extend the operation to a new set larger than $G$ if you want.  Unless you specify some restriction on the larger set, the extended operation can do anything if one of the operands is not in $G$.  For example, let $G$ be $\{0,1\}$ with the only operation of $\mod 2$ addition to make it a group.  Now I add an element $a$ to $G$ and extend the operation to include $a$ as an operand.  I can make $a+0$ be $0,1,a,$ or anything I want like $27$.

Comment: Can I support the argument by saying that *operation is not defined therefore closure is not gauranteed* for $ab \notin G$ if $a \in G,b \notin G$?

Comment: Absolutely.  If $b \not \in G, ab$ is not defined.  That is why I spoke of extending the operation so it covers $b$.